# Are Laravel's Polymorphic Relations also suitable for true polymorphism?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

To explain myself better: the [examples on Laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) showcase a relation of *comments* **belonging to** both *videos* and *posts*. However I'm talking about specification: not belonging to, but **being a specification** of the parent table. ([Subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping)) Is using Laravel's `Polymorphic Relations` still the best approach?

A very basic (and potentially bad) example.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

It is entirely possible to do what you require, with the polymorphic relation that Laravel provides. You however, are referring to table inheritance which is whole other kettle of fish.

You could have your `Animal` model have a polymorphic relationship that can either be `Fish` or `Mamal`, or you could have `Fish` and `Mamal` belong to an `Animal`, and create a pass-through model.

It really depends exactly on how you'll be using this. Will you be going through `Animal` as in querying the `animals` table, or will you be going from the children?

Comment: I will be going from the children. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Then you just want the children to belong to an animal. A pass through model would help with that. It's the way I've often gone with this.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this *pass through model*?

Comment: @ThomasMoors you'd basically override the `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` methods to reference `$this->animal->getAttribute/setAttribute()` if the provided attribute name matches an array.

Comment: Ah that sounds nice. So basically creating accessors that refference the right child / parent attribute.

Comment: Sort of, but you can override the global accessors @ThomasMoors

Comment: Sounds great, will give it a try!