# Extending one model with another model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am pretty new to laravel and currently exploring its concepts. In some videos I saw a concept of models inheritance. I wonder if we can use models relationships in laravel 5.6 then why we need to inherit models. In which case we need to or should inherit models.

eg Base Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

}
```

eg Child Model:

```
Class UserTypeOne extends User()
{
}
```

eg Child Model2:

```
Class UserTypeTwo extends User
{
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318164/extending-eloquent-models-in-laravel-use-different-tables
check above url

Comment: I've not explored it fully but it sounds good to inherit models.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486341/are-laravels-polymorphic-relations-also-suitable-for-true-polymorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to inherit Models like class inherit. You should use Eloquent Relationship instead. Prior to development, you have to do proper database designing.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships